# Logstash pipeline does not run from pipelines.yml

Tags: docker, logstash, configuration-files, elastic-stack

I am trying to run **logstash:latest** container, but pipeline is throwing an error when I run it.

When I run it directly with -f "/path/to/pipeline", everything works.
Once I run it from **pipelines.yml**, it says the pipeline has a bad formatting on the first line, first column.

**14:39:28.728 [LogStash::Runner] ERROR logstash.agent - Cannot create pipeline {:reason=>"Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 1, column 1 (byte 1) after "}**

NOTE: Before I even had a comment on the first line and it said the error is after comment, so file access and path are definitely okay.

If anyone has an idea to how or why I am experiencing this behavior, I am open to suggestions. 
At the bottom I am including my configurations.

**pipelines.yml**

```
- pipeline.id: log-pipeline
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/pipelines/log_elastic_write.conf"
  pipeline.workers: 1
```

**log_elastic_write.conf**

```
input { 
        kafka {
                bootstrap_servers => "kafka:9092"
                topics => ["logs"]
                group_id => "logs_write"
                auto_offset_reset => "earliest"
        }
}
filter {
        date {
                match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS" ]
                timezone => "UTC"
        }
}
filter {
        json {
                source => "message"
        }
}
filter {
        json {
                source => "message"
                target => "raw_message"
        }

        mutate {
                rename => {"@timestamp" => "timestamp_message_received"}
        }

        mutate {
                remove_field => [ "message" ]
                rename => {"[raw_message][timestamp]" => "timestamp_message_sent"}
        }
}
filter {
        date {
                match => ["timestamp_message_sent","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
                target => "timestamp_message_sent"
                locale => "en"
        }
}
filter {
        mutate { remove_field => [ "raw_message" ] }
        mutate { remove_field => [ "timestamp" ] }
}
output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "ipelastic:82"
                index => "logging"
        }
}
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo 'Inspecting file structure'
find /etc/logstash/ -maxdepth 4 | grep -v git | grep -v idea

echo 'Setting up runtime and pipeline configuration files(entrypoint.sh):'
echo "----------        'logstash.yml'        ----------"
envsubst < "${LOGSTASH_DIR_TARGET}/${LOGSTASH_CONFIG_SOURCE}" > "${LOGSTASH_DIR_TARGET}/${LOGSTASH_CONFIG_TARGET}"
rm "${LOGSTASH_DIR_TARGET}/${LOGSTASH_CONFIG_SOURCE}"

echo "----------        'pipelines.yml'        ----------"
envsubst < "${LOGSTASH_DIR_TARGET}/${PIPELINES_CONFIG_SOURCE}" > "${LOGSTASH_DIR_TARGET}/${PIPELINES_CONFIG_TARGET}"
rm "${LOGSTASH_DIR_TARGET}/${PIPELINES_CONFIG_SOURCE}"
less "${LOGSTASH_DIR_TARGET}/${PIPELINES_CONFIG_TARGET}"

echo "---------- pipeline: elasticsearch logs ----------"
envsubst < "${PIPELINE_DIR_TARGET}/${LOG_WRITE_PIPELINE_SOURCE}" > "${PIPELINE_DIR_TARGET}/${LOG_WRITE_PIPELINE_TARGET}"
rm "${PIPELINE_DIR_TARGET}/${LOG_WRITE_PIPELINE_SOURCE}"
less "${PIPELINE_DIR_TARGET}/${LOG_WRITE_PIPELINE_TARGET}"

chmod a+rx "${LOGSTASH_DIR_TARGET}/${LOGSTASH_CONFIG_TARGET}"
chmod a+rx "${LOGSTASH_DIR_TARGET}/${PIPELINES_CONFIG_TARGET}"
chmod a+rx "${PIPELINE_DIR_TARGET}/${LOG_WRITE_PIPELINE_TARGET}"

logstash
```

Comment: How do those files get into the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze I copy a dummy file there in the dockerfile and then use envsubst to substitute environmentals to have it dynamic, but you are seeing a direct printout of what it looks like after it is substituted, so it should be exactly what logstash has available after it is ran on ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: Can you add the entrypoint script to the question?  Can you `docker run ... sh` (using the image's entrypoint script) to validate that the config file exists and isn't empty?

Comment: @DavidMaze I ran the script with logstash -f "/etc/logstash/pipelines/log_elastic_write.conf" in ENTRYPOINT and it works. I just want to have the future option of adding pipelines. Then I inspected the files by accessing shell and they are there and have correct values. I am all out of ideas. My last chance is to specify multiple pipelines in -f option, but that seems unclean and this should work.